# Merge erroring with Unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: oracle, merge

My merge is throwing an error ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

I have spent a lot of time searching the web, and everything points to duplicate data.  I have validated that the data is not duplicated

```
table1
key, cola
1, null
2, null
3, null


table2
key, colb, colc
1, val1, c
2, val2, c
3, val3, c

merge into table1 t1
using (select * from table2 where colc = 'c') t2
on (t1.key = t2.key)
when matched then update a.cola = b.colb;
```

table1 to be updated with data from table2

I must be miss understanding the merge statement completely but cannot understand what I am doing wrong.  I'd appreciate assistance with this problem, but also a pointer as to how the merge works, ie walking through the logic process

Comment: The matching condition `t1.key = t2.key` is resulting in one to many matches(duplicate entries). So, either revisit the key being used and add few more conditions to make it a one-to-one match, or use techniques to eliminate duplicates in the source(only if the first option isn't possible)

Comment: key field is unique on both tables.

Comment: select key,count(*) from table1 group by key having count(*) >1, comes back with no rows returned.  Same when performing the select from table2

Comment: Taking that back, did find duplicate.  Odd its taken 10 hours effort to track it down.  But user error!